# Подсветить текст из введенного в input значения в тексте

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вопрос в заголовке, почему то не добавляется класс в тексте:

```js
product.forEach(function (item) {
  var product_name = item.name;
  var data_inp = $("#search_input").val();
  var searchRegex = new RegExp(data_inp, 'g');
  var new_name = product_name.replace(
    searchRegex,
    "<span class='highlight'>" + data_inp + "</span>",
  );
  var product_data = "<div class='search_ajax_prod'>" + new_name + "</div>";

  $("#search_ajax_products").append(product_data);
});
```

Comment: Добавьте немного больше информации, какой класс не добавляется, появляются ли какие-то ошибки в консоль, правильно ли обновляется DOM?

Comment: Ошибок нет, не добавляется класс highlight

Comment: Вы проверяли в отладчике, реплейс верно отрабатывает с вашей регуляркой?